# struts 1.1 tiles inside html:form

Tags: struts

Hello I had a form that looks like this:

```
<form target ="_blank" id="downloadFrm" name="downloadFrm" action="<tiles:getAsString name="downloadFileName" ignore="true"/>" method="post">
```

But I want this form to be a html:form, something like:

```
<html:form target ="_blank" styleId="downloadFrm" action="<tiles:getAsString name="downloadFileName" ignore="true"/>" >
```

But I can't have the "!tiles.getAsString inside the html:form.
I get equal symbol expected.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to assign the action to variable as follows and use it in `html:form`

```
<c:set var="actionPath"><tiles:getAsString name="downloadFileName" ignore="true"/></c:set> 

<html:form target ="_blank" styleId="downloadFrm" action="${actionPath}" />
```